# How to select subvalue of json in topic as ksql stream

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have many topics in kafka with format as such :
`value: {big json string with many subkeys etc}.`

print topic looks like :

> rowtime: 3/10/20 7:10:43 AM UTC, key: , value:  {"@timestamp": "XXXXXXXX", "beat": {"hostname": "xxxxxxxxxx","name": "xxxxxxxxxx","version": "5.2.1"}, "input_type": "log", "log_dc": "xxxxxxxxxxx", "message": "{\"server_name\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"remote_address\":\"10.x.x.x\",\"user\":\"xxxxxx\",\"timestamp_start\":\"xxxxxxxx\",\"timestamp_finish\":\"xxxxxxxxxx\",\"time_start\":\"10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000\",\"time_finish\":\"10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000\",\"request_method\":\"PUT\",\"request_uri\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"protocol\":\"HTTP/1.1\",\"status\":200,\"response_length\":\"0\",\"request_length\":\"0\",\"user_agent\":\"xxxxxxxxx\",\"request_id\":\"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\",\"request_type\":\"zzzzzzzz\",\"stat\":{\"c_wait\":0.004,\"s_wait\":0.432,\"digest\":0.0,\"commit\":31.878,\"turn_around_time\":0.0,\"t_transfer\":32.319},\"object_length\":\"0\","o_name\":\"xxxxx\",\"https\":{\"protocol\":\"TLSv1.2\",\"cipher_suite\":\"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384\"},\"principals\":{\"identity\":\"zzzzzz\",\"asv\":\"dddddddddd\"},\"type\":\"http\",\"format\":1}",     "offset": 70827770, "source": "/var/log/xxxx.log",  "type": "topicname" }

I have tried using

```
CREATE STREAM test
 (value STRUCT<
    server_name VARCHAR,
    remote_address VARCHAR,
    forwarded_for VARCHAR,
    remote_user VARCHAR,
    timestamp_start VARCHAR
 ..

WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='testing', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

But I get a stream with value as NULL.
Is there a way to grab under the value key?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question to include an actual sample of your message?

Comment: Added to question. Thanks!

Comment: How are you populating it? Looks like it comes from Elastic Beats?

Comment: If you use something like kafkacat to dump the raw message, is it actually escaped JSON within JSON like the `PRINT` shows?

Comment: Yes. The json in the message field is escaped JSON. And yes it comes from beats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escaped JSON is not valid JSON, which is probably going to have made this more difficult :)

In this snippet:

```js
…\"object_length\":\"0\","o_name\":\"xxxxx\",\"https\":{\"protocol\":\…
```

the leading double-quote for `o_name` is not escaped. You can validate this with something like `jq`:

```sh
echo '{"message": "{\"server_name\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"remote_address\":\"10.x.x.x\",\"user\":\"xxxxxx\",\"timestamp_start\":\"xxxxxxxx\",\"timestamp_finish\":\"xxxxxxxxxx\",\"time_start\":\"10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000\",\"time_finish\":\"10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000\",\"request_method\":\"PUT\",\"request_uri\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"protocol\":\"HTTP/1.1\",\"status\":200,\"response_length\":\"0\",\"request_length\":\"0\",\"user_agent\":\"xxxxxxxxx\",\"request_id\":\"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\",\"request_type\":\"zzzzzzzz\",\"stat\":{\"c_wait\":0.004,\"s_wait\":0.432,\"digest\":0.0,\"commit\":31.878,\"turn_around_time\":0.0,\"t_transfer\":32.319},\"object_length\":\"0\","o_name\":\"xxxxx\",\"https\":{\"protocol\":\"TLSv1.2\",\"cipher_suite\":\"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384\"},\"principals\":{\"identity\":\"zzzzzz\",\"asv\":\"dddddddddd\"},\"type\":\"http\",\"format\":1}"}' | jq '.message|fromjson'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 685
```

With the JSON fixed this then parses successfully:

```sh
➜ echo '{"message": "{\"server_name\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"remote_address\":\"10.x.x.x\",\"user\":\"xxxxxx\",\"timestamp_start\":\"xxxxxxxx\",\"timestamp_finish\":\"xxxxxxxxxx\",\"time_start\":\"10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000\",\"time_finish\":\"10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000\",\"request_m
ethod\":\"PUT\",\"request_uri\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"protocol\":\"HTTP/1.1\",\"status\":200,\"response_length\":\"0\",\"request_length\":\"0\",\"user_agent\":\"xxxxxxxxx\",\"request_id\":\"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\",\"request_type\":\"zzzzzzzz\",\"stat\":{\"c_wait\":0.004,\"s_
wait\":0.432,\"digest\":0.0,\"commit\":31.878,\"turn_around_time\":0.0,\"t_transfer\":32.319},\"object_length\":\"0\",\"o_name\":\"xxxxx\",\"https\":{\"protocol\":\"TLSv1.2\",\"cipher_suite\":\"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384\"},\"principals\":{\"identity\":\"zzzzzz\",\"asv\":\"dddd
dddddd\"},\"type\":\"http\",\"format\":1}"}' | jq '.message|fromjson'
{
  "server_name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "remote_address": "10.x.x.x",
  "user": "xxxxxx",
  "timestamp_start": "xxxxxxxx",
  "timestamp_finish": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "time_start": "10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000",
  "time_finish": "10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000",
  "request_method": "PUT",
  "request_uri": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
  "status": 200,
…
```

---

So now let's get this into ksqlDB. I'm using kafkacat to load it into a topic:

```sh
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t testing -P<<EOF
{ "@timestamp": "XXXXXXXX", "beat": { "hostname": "xxxxxxxxxx", "name": "xxxxxxxxxx", "version": "5.2.1" }, "input_type": "log", "log_dc": "xxxxxxxxxxx", "message": "{\"server_name\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"remote_address\":\"10.x.x.x\",\"user\":\"xxxxxx\",\"timestamp_start\":\"xxxxxxxx\",\"timestamp_finish\":\"xxxxxxxxxx\",\"time_start\":\"10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000\",\"time_finish\":\"10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000\",\"request_method\":\"PUT\",\"request_uri\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"protocol\":\"HTTP/1.1\",\"status\":200,\"response_length\":\"0\",\"request_length\":\"0\",\"user_agent\":\"xxxxxxxxx\",\"request_id\":\"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz\",\"request_type\":\"zzzzzzzz\",\"stat\":{\"c_wait\":0.004,\"s_wait\":0.432,\"digest\":0.0,\"commit\":31.878,\"turn_around_time\":0.0,\"t_transfer\":32.319},\"object_length\":\"0\",\"o_name\":\"xxxxx\",\"https\":{\"protocol\":\"TLSv1.2\",\"cipher_suite\":\"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384\"},\"principals\":{\"identity\":\"zzzzzz\",\"asv\":\"dddddddddd\"},\"type\":\"http\",\"format\":1}", "offset": 70827770, "source": "/var/log/xxxx.log", "type": "topicname" }
EOF
```

Now with ksqlDB let's declare the outline schema, in which the `message` field is just a lump of `VARCHAR`:

```sql
CREATE STREAM TEST (BEAT STRUCT<HOSTNAME VARCHAR, NAME VARCHAR, VERSION VARCHAR>,
                    INPUT_TYPE VARCHAR, 
                    MESSAGE VARCHAR, 
                    OFFSET BIGINT, 
                    SOURCE VARCHAR) 
            WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='testing', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

We can query this stream to check that it's working:

```sql
SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
SELECT BEAT->HOSTNAME, 
       BEAT->VERSION, 
       SOURCE, 
       MESSAGE 
  FROM TEST 
EMIT CHANGES LIMIT 1;
```

```
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|BEAT__HOSTNAME   |BEAT__VERSION  |SOURCE              |MESSAGE                                                             |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|xxxxxxxxxx       |5.2.1          |/var/log/xxxx.log   |{"server_name":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","remote_address":"10.x.x.x","user":|
|                 |               |                    |"xxxxxx","timestamp_start":"xxxxxxxx","timestamp_finish":"xxxxxxxxxx|
|                 |               |                    |","time_start":"10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000","time_finish":"10/Mar/20|
|                 |               |                    |20:07:10:39 +0000","request_method":"PUT","request_uri":"xxxxxxxxxxx|
|                 |               |                    |xxxxxxxxxxxx","protocol":"HTTP/1.1","status":200,"response_length":"|
|                 |               |                    |0","request_length":"0","user_agent":"xxxxxxxxx","request_id":"zzzzz|
|                 |               |                    |zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz","request_type":"zzzzzzzz","stat":{"c_wait":0.004,"|
|                 |               |                    |s_wait":0.432,"digest":0.0,"commit":31.878,"turn_around_time":0.0,"t|
|                 |               |                    |_transfer":32.319},"object_length":"0","o_name":"xxxxx","https":{"pr|
|                 |               |                    |otocol":"TLSv1.2","cipher_suite":"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"},|
|                 |               |                    |"principals":{"identity":"zzzzzz","asv":"dddddddddd"},"type":"http",|
|                 |               |                    |"format":1}                                                         |
Limit Reached
Query terminated
```

Now let's extract the embedded JSON fields using the `EXTRACTJSONFIELD` function (I've not done every field, just a handful of them to illustrate the pattern to follow):

```sql
SELECT EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.remote_address')        AS REMOTE_ADDRESS,
       EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.time_start')            AS TIME_START,
       EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.protocol')              AS PROTOCOL,
       EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.status')                AS STATUS,
       EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.stat.c_wait')           AS STAT_C_WAIT,
       EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.stat.s_wait')           AS STAT_S_WAIT,
       EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.stat.digest')           AS STAT_DIGEST,
       EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.stat.commit')           AS STAT_COMMIT,
       EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.stat.turn_around_time') AS STAT_TURN_AROUND_TIME,
       EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.stat.t_transfer')       AS STAT_T_TRANSFER 
  FROM TEST 
EMIT CHANGES LIMIT 1;
```

```
+----------------+--------------------------+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+----------------------+----------------+
|REMOTE_ADDRESS  |TIME_START                |PROTOCOL  |STATUS  |STAT_C_WAIT |STAT_S_WAIT  |STAT_DIGEST |STAT_COMMIT |STAT_TURN_AROUND_TIME |STAT_T_TRANSFER |
+----------------+--------------------------+----------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+----------------------+----------------+
|10.x.x.x        |10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000|HTTP/1.1  |200     |0.004       |0.432        |0           |31.878      |0                     |32.319          |
```

We can persist this to a new Kafka topic, and for good measure reserialise it to Avro to make it easier for downstream applications to use:

```sql
CREATE STREAM BEATS WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS
    SELECT EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.remote_address')        AS REMOTE_ADDRESS,
        EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.time_start')            AS TIME_START,
        EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.protocol')              AS PROTOCOL,
        EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.status')                AS STATUS,
        EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.stat.c_wait')           AS STAT_C_WAIT,
        EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.stat.s_wait')           AS STAT_S_WAIT,
        EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.stat.digest')           AS STAT_DIGEST,
        EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.stat.commit')           AS STAT_COMMIT,
        EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.stat.turn_around_time') AS STAT_TURN_AROUND_TIME,
        EXTRACTJSONFIELD(MESSAGE,'$.stat.t_transfer')       AS STAT_T_TRANSFER 
    FROM TEST 
    EMIT CHANGES LIMIT 1;
```

```sql
ksql> DESCRIBE BEATS;

Name                 : BEATS
 Field                 | Type
---------------------------------------------------
 ROWTIME               | BIGINT           (system)
 ROWKEY                | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
 REMOTE_ADDRESS        | VARCHAR(STRING)
 TIME_START            | VARCHAR(STRING)
 PROTOCOL              | VARCHAR(STRING)
 STATUS                | VARCHAR(STRING)
 STAT_C_WAIT           | VARCHAR(STRING)
 STAT_S_WAIT           | VARCHAR(STRING)
 STAT_DIGEST           | VARCHAR(STRING)
 STAT_COMMIT           | VARCHAR(STRING)
 STAT_TURN_AROUND_TIME | VARCHAR(STRING)
 STAT_T_TRANSFER       | VARCHAR(STRING)
---------------------------------------------------
For runtime statistics and query details run: DESCRIBE EXTENDED <Stream,Table>;
```

---

To debug issues with ksqlDB returning NULLs check out [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-1/). A lot of the time it's down to serialisation errors. For example, if you look at the ksqlDB server log you'll see this error when it tries to parse the badly-formed escaped JSON before I fixed it:

```
WARN Exception caught during Deserialization, taskId: 0_0, topic: testing, partition: 0, offset: 1 (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread:36)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: mvn value from topic: testing
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('o' (code 111)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"@timestamp": "XXXXXXXX", "beat": {"hostname": "xxxxxxxxxx","name": "xxxxxxxxxx","version": "5.2.1"}, "input_type": "log", "log_dc": "xxxxxxxxxxx", "message": "{\"server_name\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"remote_address\":\"10.x.x.x\",\"user\":\
"xxxxxx\",\"timestamp_start\":\"xxxxxxxx\",\"timestamp_finish\":\"xxxxxxxxxx\",\"time_start\":\"10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000\",\"time_finish\":\"10/Mar/2020:07:10:39 +0000\",\"request_method\":\"PUT\",\"request_uri\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"protocol\":\"HT"[truncated 604 bytes];
 line: 1, column: 827]
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:693)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:591)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:986)
…
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I am amazed at the effort you went to to help me. Much much appreciated.